# Dynamic User in .bat file

Tags: ms-access, batch-file

This is my first time trying to use .bat files. I am trying to make one that keeps my front end of my Access database on the most current version for users (only ~7).

I am using:

```
md C:\Users\tmyers\Desktop
del C:\Users\tmyers\Desktop\Quotations.accdr
copy "\Users\counter1152\desktop\PM DESKTOP FILES\Lighting Project Management Application\Quotations.accdr" C:\Users\tmyers\Desktop
C:\Users\tmyers\Desktop\Quotations.accdr
```

Part of the copy string I removed due to being the path to our server (just in case). I need the user to somehow be dynamic based on the person executing the file. I could make a special .bat file for each person since I dont have many users, but that seems sloppy.

As a secondary question, how can I get the cmd prompt window to not show when this is executed? That would just be a personal preference of mine. I did find https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window for reference but am not 100% sure how to do wscript.

Comment: use %userprofile%

Comment: Just to make sure, so in this instance I would replace my name (tmyers) with that?

Comment: You may get some inspiration from my article [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with :

```
md "%userprofile%\Desktop"
del "%userprofile%\Desktop\Quotations.accdr"
copy "\Users\counter1152\desktop\PM DESKTOP FILES\Lighting Project Management Application\Quotations.accdr" "%userprofile%\Desktop"
"%userprofile%\Desktop\Quotations.accdr"
```

To auto-hide the cmd.exe window you can use [windowmode.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) and [getCMDPid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat):

```
call getcmdbit.bat
call windowmode.bat -pid %errorlevel% -mode hidden
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for that. Any chance you have insight on the second part of my question? This was the main thing I was after however.